# MVC: second parameter for SqlCommand appearing as Null in Database

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, datetime

I can't figure out why my second parameter (`NotifyDateParameter`) for my `SqlCommand` isn't working properly. It does not give an error, but it appears as null in my SQL Server database. The first parameter (`StringParameter`) appears just as intended. I could use some of your expertise right about now.

```
try
{
    {
        string connstr = @"Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=ImageDB;Trusted_Connection=True;";

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstr);
        conn.Open();

        string query;
        byte[] fileData = null;

        using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(Request.Files[upload].InputStream))
        {
            fileData = binaryReader.ReadBytes(Request.Files[upload].ContentLength);
        }

        query = "insert into Images(ImageData, NotifyDate) values(@ImageData, @NotifyDate)";

        SqlParameter StringParameter = new SqlParameter();
        StringParameter.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarBinary;
        StringParameter.ParameterName = "ImageData";
        StringParameter.Value = fileData;

        DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime notifyDate = today.AddDays(1);
        //string notifyDateString = notifyDate.ToString();

        SqlParameter NotifyDateParameter = new SqlParameter();
        NotifyDateParameter.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.DateTime;
        NotifyDateParameter.ParameterName = "NotifyDate";
        NotifyDateParameter.Value = notifyDate;

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);

        cmd.Parameters.Add(StringParameter);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(NotifyDateParameter);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();       

        cmd.Dispose();
        conn.Close();
        conn.Dispose();
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    string exceptionCause = String.Format("An error occurred: '{0}'", e);
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\Nathan\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\MVCImageUpload\uploads\exception.txt", exceptionCause);
}
```

Comment: What is the data type of NotifyDate on the SQL table itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well for starters do try 2 things

1. Replace `NotifyDateParameter.ParameterName = "NotifyDate";` with `NotifyDateParameter.ParameterName = "@NotifyDate"; // @added to parameter name`.
2. Check if parameter type is `SqlDbType.DateTime` or `SqlDbType.Date`

Comment: Changing it to "@NotifyDate" worked! Thank you. I'm just curious though, why is it that I am not required to add the "@" character before "ImageData" in order for that to work? That parameter has been working without it...

Comment: @Vigs - happened to me before as well. I was not able to find the logic behind that.